# Add Service Reference error "Cannot import wsdl:portType"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, soap, visual-studio-2012, servicestack, service-reference

I cannot get the Add Service Reference in VS 2010 or 2012 to work for web services built on ServiceStack . I have followed the [guide](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support) on github, including adding the ContractNameSpace attribute to the AssemblyInfo.cs file and ensuring all my DTOs are in the same namespace but with no luck. Instead I receive a number of build warnings error messages that I have included below.

Does anybody have any suggestions about what is going wrong?

```
Warning 1 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Schema with target namespace 'http://schemas.servicestack.net/types' could not be found.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:portType[@name='ISyncReply']

Warning 2 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:portType[@name='ISyncReply']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:binding[@name='WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply']

Warning 3 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:binding[@name='WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:service[@name='SyncReply']/wsdl:port[@name='WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply']

Warning 4 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Schema with target namespace 'http://schemas.servicestack.net/types' could not be found.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:portType[@name='IOneWay']

Warning 5 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:portType[@name='IOneWay']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:binding[@name='WSHttpBinding_IOneWay']

Warning 6 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:binding[@name='WSHttpBinding_IOneWay']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:service[@name='AsyncOneWay']/wsdl:port[@name='WSHttpBinding_IOneWay']

Warning 1 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Schema with target namespace 'http://schemas.servicestack.net/types' could not be found.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:portType[@name='ISyncReply']

Warning 2 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:portType[@name='ISyncReply']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:binding[@name='WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply']

Warning 3 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:binding[@name='WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:service[@name='SyncReply']/wsdl:port[@name='WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply']

Warning 4 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Schema with target namespace 'http://schemas.servicestack.net/types' could not be found.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:portType[@name='IOneWay']

Warning 5 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:portType[@name='IOneWay']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:binding[@name='WSHttpBinding_IOneWay']

Warning 6 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:binding[@name='WSHttpBinding_IOneWay']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:service[@name='AsyncOneWay']/wsdl:port[@name='WSHttpBinding_IOneWay']
```

Comment: Does disabling "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" in the Service Reference Configuration help?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please use the comment section to leave question

Comment: I'm really struggling with this one as well, my DTO's have datacontract and datamember attribtutes on them though and I've made them really simple to try and just get it working, still crashes just like yours above

Comment: @Ozz Its best if you could create a separate question for your issue including the test code. Once you have done this I can have a look and see if I can identify the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discovered the root of my problem. One of my DTOs was not decorated with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes.

This meant the WSDL produced by ServiceStack didn't contain the type information for this DTO, so when one of the message sub-sections of the WSDL referred to this DTO type VS couldn't find it and threw the exception.

Hopefully this will help someone else. It took me quite a bit of time to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Yeah this is already listed in the [SOAP Support wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support) at `Make sure that DTO objects have [DataContract] attribute...`

Answer (score 0):

Another reason could be :Check targetNamespace could have created conflict, remove any instance of tempuri.org - put consistent namespace appropriately, would resolve above error.

```
targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IMyInterafaceService'
```

Hope it helps

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with using `tempuri.org`, as long as it is used consistently.