# Impossible to add web reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, soap-client

I'm tryin to use soap service in Visual Studio 2010 with c#. I go ad try new service reference but I always get that error

> Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference
> 'easyZM'.  Please check other error and warning messages for
> details.  path\Service References\serviceTest\Reference.svcmap

with those warning:

> Warning   13  Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
>
> Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
>
> Error: Cannot find definition for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/:putDkm.  Service Description with namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ is missing.
>
> Parameter name: name
>
> XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:Easy']/wsdl:portType[@name='EasyPort']    path\Service References\serviceTest\Reference.svcmap

I have no idea what to do. I have looked at that question [What does this WCF error mean: "Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872865/what-does-this-wcf-error-mean-custom-tool-warning-cannot-import-wsdlporttype) but none of solutions provided there worked for me.

Path to wsdl: https://ews.zav-mb.si/easy/wsdl/easy.wsdl

Any ideas?

Can somebody else try and report his results?

I found out that problem is likely with the wsdl file itself. But I have no idea how to fix it.

```
<definitions xmlns:tns="urn:Easy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="Easy" targetNamespace="urn:Easy">
<types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Hello">
    <xsd:element name="fileName" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="fileContent" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="fileSize" type="xsd:int"/>
    <xsd:element name="easyDocRef" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="message" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="result" type="xsd:boolean"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</types>

<message name="putDkm">
    <part name="fileName" type="tns:fileName"/>
    <part name="fileContentBase64Encoded" type="tns:fileContent"/>
    <part name="fileSize" type="tns:fileSize"/>
</message>
<message name="putDkmResponse">
    <part name="result" type="tns:result"/>
    <part name="message" type="tns:message"/>
    <part name="easyDocref" type="tns:easyDocRef"/>
</message>
<!--  get stuff  -->
<message name="get">
    <part name="easyDocRef" type="tns:getEasyDocRef"/>
</message>
<message name="getResponse">
    <part name="result" type="tns:result"/>
    <part name="message" type="tns:message"/>
    <part name="fileContentBase64Encoded" type="tns:fileContent"/>
    <part name="fileName" type="tns:fileName"/>
</message>
<portType name="EasyPort">
    <operation name="putDkm">
        <input message="putDkm"/>
        <output message="tns:putDkmResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="get">
        <input message="get"/>
        <output message="tns:getResponse"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="EasyBinding" type="tns:EasyPort">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="putDkm">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:putDkmAction"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:Easy" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:Easy" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="get">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:getAction"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:Easy" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:Easy" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="EasyService">
    <port name="EasyPort" binding="tns:EasyBinding">
        <soap:address location="https://ews.zav-mb.si/easy/index.php"/>
    </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Is this still current? I just added a service reference for https://ews.zav-mb.si/easy/wsdl/easy.wsdl in VS 2010 without any issues...

Comment: Can u please report how u do it? I managed to hack my way trough but the hard way.

Comment: Do you have your project set to target a client framework? e.g. .NET Framework 4.0 Client?

Comment: Nowp i'm targeting 3.5 FRamework.

Comment: Are you in control of creating the service? I have found that adding an assembly that has interfaces your service supports is easier. Add a contracts assembly and create the connections to the service yourself. Personally I don't like the add service reference.

Comment: `I found out that problem is likely with the wsdl file itself. But I have no idea how to fix it.` No, you don't do anything wrong. It is the the wsdl provider to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely there's a problem with WSDL.
I had the same warning. Then I changed

```
<portType name="EasyPort">
    <operation name="putDkm">
        <input message="putDkm"/>
        <output message="tns:putDkmResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="get">
        <input message="get"/>
        <output message="tns:getResponse"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
```

to

```
<portType name="EasyPort">
    <operation name="putDkm">
        <input message="tns:putDkm"/>
        <output message="tns:putDkmResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="get">
        <input message="tns:get"/>
        <output message="tns:getResponse"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
```

(See the namespace)
After that the build was successful, however no client code had been generated.
I'm not going to fix everything, but may I suggest you to firstly create a service prototype with the same interface, generate its WSDL and compare the result with what you have at the moment.

Comment: I finaly get creators of web service to start fixxing it by providing them some data. So thank u!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have fixed the issue already:(

I gave a try with svcutil.exe to generate proxy class for the service. Proxy was not generated but gave some errors. Attached is the errors I got on the console.
[image]
cent percent I believe, it is problem with the service because a similar question was found in another post that was fixed by modifying the service. Review your code in the service, you will certainly be able to fix this issue.

[Add Service Reference error “Cannot import wsdl:portType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191372/add-service-reference-error-cannot-import-wsdlporttype)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue sometime back in my project, apparently the issue was that the folder where the reference files were generated was read only and the hence the files were not overwritten , try removing the read only folder attribute for that folder and the entire project and then reopen the solution.It should successfully generate now.